# Asp .Net Mvc Bundle wrong scripts' path

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I've got an ASP. NET MVC Project with BundleConfig declaring jquery, bootstrap and modernizr scripts. It works fine on localhost, and the path to scripts lead to exact `.js` file.

But after publishing to the hosting, the scripts fail to load with the following error message:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
`http://example.com/bundles/jquery?v=SomeStrangeIdHere`

Why is the path changed? And how can I load my scripts properly?

Comment: What do you mean the path changed? And are the original .js scripts published to host as well?

Comment: I figured out. The problem is in my route configuration. It adds the culture token to the default route.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your NuGet Package - upgrade your jquery and modernize.

Rebuild your .dll files and re-push up your code. If you are still getting the error then I would look at your _layout.cshtml and make sure at the bottom of your HTML its something like ...

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/integrationpoint")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Lastly I would check under your Scripts folder to see if you had jquery being loaded.

(Also, when you say it works locally - are you sure its not cached? If your using Chrome do Clt + Shift + R for a Hard Reload.)